# How to display image on the Tkinter window?

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to create Tkinter GUI for an Image generator in which once an user clicks on the 'Generate Image' button, it should display 'diff-overlay.jpg' on the window. Note that this file is in the same directory.

I've created the method(command) 'generate' to display the image on the window. But the button 'Generate Image' is not displaying the image(diff-overlay.jpg).Can someone help me on where am I going wrong in this? Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk

import numpy as np


from PIL import ImageTk,Image  #for image in tk

class HeatMap(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent=0):
        self.mainWindow = Frame(parent)
        self.fTop = Frame(self.mainWindow)
        self.fTop.pack(fill="both",expand =True)


        self.button = Button(self.fTop, text='Generate Image',command=self.generate)
        self.button.pack(side="right")

        self.mainWindow.pack(fill="both")

    #this should display the image on the root window
    def generate(self):
        image = Image.open('diff-overlay.jpg')
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        w1 = tk.Label(root, image=photo).pack(side="right",expand=True)



root = Tk()
root.title("Image Generator")
root.geometry("1200x1200")
app=HeatMap(root)

root.mainloop()
```

.

Comment: There are likely dozens of questions on this site about images not showing up. Did you do any research before asking this question?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it:

```
def iniImage():
    img = Image.open("image.png")
    img = img.resize((300,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    panel = Label(window, image=img)
    panel.image = img
    panel.place(relheight=.095,relwidth=0.25,relx=0.7,rely=0.03)
```

And to be able to use a .jpg image, i think you'll have to use something like:

```
path = "image.jpg"

#Creates a Tkinter-compatible photo image, which can be used everywhere Tkinter expects an image object.
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by storing the image object.

```
self.iconPath = 'diff-overlay.jpg'
self.icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.iconPath))
self.icon_size = Label(root)
self.icon_size.image = self.icon  
self.icon_size.configure(image=self.icon)
self.icon_size.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True)
```